# Accidentally deleted my custom color palette and need to retrieve it

Tags: color, corel-draw, palette

I work in CorelDraw CS2 on a PC and just accidentally deleted my color palette on the right side of my project page.

It has all custom colors I've added over the years for projects and is actually a different set of colors found in the fill tool on the left. How can I recover this palette?

Comment: Did you _delete_ the contents of the palette, or have you just hidden the palette window?

Comment: Not sure. I mis-clicked on the color palette and it brought it away from the right edge and made it into a square on the working page so I hit the x to delete that thinking it was something I didn't need and then all my color boxes on the right were gone. I tried the Window to Docker to User's Palette but it wasn't there. I've never saved my color palette directly.

Comment: I am useless at CorelDraw, but sounds to me like you minimised the palette, and you might find it again by checking out the various menues. Hopefully a CorelDraw expert will pop up here soon.

Comment: You said you tried Window>Docker, at the risk of asking an obvious question, did you try Window>Color Palettes? Also, you might want to check your My Documents/My Palettes folder, see if there's anything there...

Answer (score 1):

If your CorelDraw setup files are english it's basically located in **C:\Program Files\Corel\CorelDRAW(Version)\Color\Palettes**. You can search the folder directly as visually. If you can't reach the **Palettes** folder by the default path you can make a windows search in **C:\Program Files\Corel** folder as "palet".

Check this image:
[image: Default Color Palettes Path in Windows]

It's a too late answer but i hope it may help the other designers if they have the same trobule.

Answer (score -1):

It's very simple. Click Window, next to Tool on your menu bar on top. Then go to Color Palettes and check the box: Default CMYK Palette. That's it!

Comment: Hi Roman! Welcome to GD.SE, and thanks for your answer. Although I'm not entirely sure if this is an answer to the question. But I'll leave it to the OP to decide.

Answer (score -1):

It's very simple. Click Window, next to Tool on your menu bar on top. Then go to Color Palettes and check the box: Default CMYK Palette and click on Uniform colors That's it!

Comment: What possibly purpose does it have to repeat an existing answer!?